# Calling a TS Function from Script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm Using a external JS from an external enterprise. Is mandatory use this script online and not import it.

one of the complexity is that they've his own html tag to call a functions that are inside from a script tag. I've created this script from typescript side to control some variables, but i need to call a function to have a value needed in the end of the flux.

So, in short, I need call a TypeScript Function from this script tag created.

here some code:

```
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = `text/javascript`;
    script.text = `
    var success = function (data) {
        let transactions= ${JSON.stringify(this.transactions)};
        let internalId = this.getInternalId('Hello there!'); -----> The TS Function that I want to call
    };`;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
    
    getInternalId(value:string):void {
    console.log('a');
   }
```

greetings!

**UPDATE**

I tried to abstract the function in the HTML tag like this:

```
    [attr.data-order-id]="success"
```

and in the ts file like this:

```
    success = (data:any ) => {
    debugger;
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.transactions;));
  };
```

But I lost every reference of the proyect and somehow it function is executed from other file:

[image: The function is executed from another file. on the left tab is the ts file where function is declarated functions]

The function is executed from another file. On the left tab is the ts file where function is declarated.

Comment: At a first glance this looks like a big security risk.

Comment: I agree with arwed, this looks like quite a strange implementation. Is the ‘TS function’ you mention a function somewhere in an Angular component?

Comment: I mean you can compile the ts code at runtime using the compiler API. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

But then you must bundle it and it is still in most cases unnecessary and dangerous.

Comment: If you're just running code in devtools, TypeScript won't work. TS also won't work in `<script>` tags - it must be compiled.

Comment: I've updated the alternative solution, but it doesn't work

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just rewrite this in JS?

Comment: @DanielM I don´t get your question. What do you mean?

Comment: If you rewrite the script in JS you can just import it